# Android SmsManager Fails to Send

Tags: android, android-studio, smsmanager

I already have an activity in my app that sends an SMS message so I thought it would be easy to copy some code across to another activity, but no! I am trying to put two buttons on MainActivity to send pre-written SMS messages. The full MainActivity.java is:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE = 10;
    private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_SEND = 20;
    Button button_8;
    Button button_9;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkPermission();
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button_8 = findViewById(R.id.availability_8);
        button_8.setOnClickListener(view -> sendSMS8());
        button_9 = findViewById(R.id.availability_9);
        button_9.setOnClickListener(view -> sendSMS9());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_most_recent_tasking:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ShoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;

            case R.id.action_about:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void sendSMS8() {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(getString(R.string.at_number), null, "8", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.a_sent,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.a_failed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void sendSMS9() {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(getString(R.string.at_number), null, "9", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.a_sent,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.a_failed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void checkPermission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);
        }
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_SEND);
        }
    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest file includes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

and

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CgPager.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I just cannot see why this is not working. (Each time I run it, the toast reports "Availability failed to send" ie string.a_failed.

For comparison, this code is working on another activity:

```
    protected void sendSMS1() {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(getString(R.string.at_number), null, "1", null, null);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean partner_text =  sharedPreferences.getBoolean("partner", false);
        if(partner_text){
            String text_message =  sharedPreferences.getString("partner_textmessage", "");
            String partner_telno =  sharedPreferences.getString("partner_phone", "");
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(partner_telno, null, text_message, null, null);
        }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String shoutContent = intent.getStringExtra(ReceiveAlertActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        Intent secondintent = new Intent(this, ShoutActivity.class);
        secondintent.putExtra(MESSAGE, shoutContent);
        startActivity(secondintent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.r_sent,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.r_failed,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1. The code you wrote shows that the `android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` permission is obtained when you open the file for the first time, not the permission to send SMS messages.
   `The android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS permission` is obtained only when you open the file for the second time.

   The solution is to add the callback method (`onRequestPermissionsResult`) of the request permission result. The next permission can be applied only after the callback method is executed for multiple times.
2. The following provides a simple solution to this problem by implementing the `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)` method.

   a. Obtain the permission in the **Activity**.

   [image]

   b.
   [image]
3. The following is a complex method of obtaining permissions in batches. The following is an example.

   a. Add the permission to be dynamically obtained to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
   [image]

   b. Obtain permissions in batches in **Activity**:
   [image]

   c. Perform the processing after obtaining the permission in the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method.
   [image]

---

1. You are advised to view the logs about SMS message sending failures to locate the cause.
   You can view logs on the Android Studio console. The filtering field is **SMS**.

   For example, if you do not have the permission to send SMS messages, the following log is generated when the code for sending SMS messages is invoked:

   [image]
2. You can also change the **Msg** in the **Toast message** so that you can view the cause of the SMS message sending failure through the Toast message.

   Toast Msg can be changed to `""+e.getMessage()`

   [image]

   Error message:

   [image]
3. Take a Huawei phone as an example.
   After the app obtains the permission to send SMS messages, a warning dialog box is displayed when you send the message for the first time, as shown in the following figure.

   [image]

   [image]
4. so It's recommended that you to view the logs to find the cause of the failure to send SMS messages.

Comment: Brilliant info Shirley. Thanks. Especially the bit about getting the error message included in the toast.
And there's my problem: uid 10359 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS. So now I just have to puzzle out why.
I've got  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> in the manifest.
There's checkSelfPermission in the java file that covers Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS.
And there is another activity in the same app that is sending SMS perfectly, that I copied and pasted the code from.

Comment: It turns out that when the app is first downloaded from Android Studio to my phone, I get the error. If I close the app and open it again, it works!!!! So now I have to find out if it works out of the box when the APK has been downloaded and installed in the conventional production way. Still puzzled, but relieved.

Comment: HI@ TrapezeArtist,i just upadated my answer,pls kindly refer,hope this could help

Comment: Shirley, I think that does help. And it leads me to a much simpler solution. MainActivity only sends SMS. It doesn't receive. So I think I can simply remove the line that references Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, leaving Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS. I'll have to do some testing, and I don't have time right now but I'll get onto it later or tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure You can test it and It would be great to upvote my answer if it was helpful to you.  Thanks :)